# Populating a custom field from the Wordpress Postie Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Postie plugin to auto post from email on my Wp blog.
I am trying to populate two custom fields (mail_meta_from and mail_meta_replyto") with the "from" and "reply to" fields

```
add_filter('postie_post_before', 'add_custom_field');

//Get the "from" and "replyto" email details

add_filter('postie_filter_email2', 'get_emaildetails', 10, 3);
function get_emaildetails( $from, $toEmail, $replytoEmail) {
  DebugEcho("step-01b");
  DebugDump("from " . $from);
  DebugDump("toEmail " . $toEmail);
  DebugDump("replytoEmail " . $replytoEmail);
  $fromField = $from;
  $replytoEmail = $replytoEmail;

  return $from;
  return $replytoEmail;
function add_custom_field($post) {
    add_post_meta($post['ID'], 'mail_meta_from', '$from');
    add_post_meta($post['ID'], 'mail_meta_replyto', $replytoEmail);
    return $post;
}
}
```

This has been driving me nuts for the past 2 days, and I have tried multiple  variations of the above but with no success.
At the moment, I am getting the error

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'add_custom_field' not found or invalid function name in /home/sites/mysite.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 213
```

I try and learn from my mistakes, but I am not getting anywhere with this...
The default answer for help with this on the WP forum is to check out http://postieplugin.com/extending/.

Which I have... repeatedly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps I should have added that I am editing the filterPostie.php file

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the `add_custom_field()` function inside the scope of the `get_emaildetails()` function because it is within the curly braces. You should also consider using a more unique name for your function, or encapsulate it an an object namespace. The error you are getting indicates that when the `apply_filter()` is called for `postie_post_before` it can't find a function called `add_custom_field()`. Use the code below to properly scope the function, though note that you have some other syntax errors as well.

```
add_filter('postie_post_before', 'add_custom_field');
function add_custom_field($post) {
    // the variable $from is not defined, and it will not evaluate if enclosed 
    // in single quotes. if you want the value of $from define it then use "{$from}"
    add_post_meta($post['ID'], 'mail_meta_from', '$from');
    // $replytoEmail is not defined
    add_post_meta($post['ID'], 'mail_meta_replyto', $replytoEmail);
    return $post;
}

//Get the "from" and "replyto" email details
add_filter('postie_filter_email2', 'get_emaildetails', 10, 3);
function get_emaildetails( $from, $toEmail, $replytoEmail) {
  DebugEcho("step-01b");
  DebugDump("from " . $from);
  DebugDump("toEmail " . $toEmail);
  DebugDump("replytoEmail " . $replytoEmail);
  // what is this for?
  $fromField = $from;

  // setting to itself, then not used?
  $replytoEmail = $replytoEmail;

  return $from;

  // this will never return?
  return $replytoEmail;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
Like I said I learn from my mistakes and this definatly gives me something to go on... appreciate it